# Copying two images into one image with OpenCV 2.4.2

Tags: xcode, opencv

I am trying to copy two images into one big image, but unfortunately i am unable to insert just 1 image with following attempt:

```
void showTwoImages(Mat imageOne, Mat imageTwo, string title) {
    int totalCol = imageOne.cols+imageTwo.cols;
    int totalRow = imageOne.rows;

    Mat totalImage(Size(totalCol, totalRow), 8, 3);

    imageOne.copyTo(totalImage(Rect(0,0,imageOne.cols, imageOne.rows)));

    viewImage(totalImage, title);
}
```

My error:

[image]

Unfortunately i do not get an specific error from within XCode, but reference to the assembler code, so i am unable to determine the error occured.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
Mat totalImage(Size(totalCol, totalRow), 8, 3);
```

to

```
Mat totalImage(Size(totalCol, totalRow), imageOne.type());
```